# Is a kit lens capable enough to take snaps at engagement event?

Tags: canon-600d, kit-lens, photography-basics

I have a Canon 600D with twin kit lenses (EF-S 18-55 IS II & EF-S 55-250 IS II). Can I take snaps with it at engagement event? If yes, then what settings should I stick to?

Comment: This question is too broad, unclear and primarily opinion based. Please take a look at [ask] and try again.

Comment: Particularly, what settings you should use will vary greatly depending upon the actual lighting environment. Outside at noon on a sunny day? Inside a dark night club? At the office where one of the engagees works (what kind of lights? How bright? How close and what size are the nearest windows, if any)? At a public park at twilight?

Comment: In my opinion someone else event it is NOT the best scenario to start learning how to use a camera.

Comment: Do you want to take 'snaps' or photographs ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, of course you *can* take pictures with them. Will the pictures be as good as a professional would get more expensive lenses? No - but then a beginner won't get as good photos even if they're given the best lenses in the world.

If you don't know what settings to use, your best bet is almost certainly to use either full auto or program mode and let the camera guess for you. The most important thing you need to do is to consider light - particularly with the relatively slow speed of the kit lenses, you're going to struggle in most indoor scenarios. Don't be afraid to use the flash - it's better than nothing, even if you will get a bit of the "rabbit in the headlights" look. Ideally, get a flash you can bounce or use off-camera.